# Minecraft Crash OpenAL

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, windows-10

I need help, Minecraft keeps crashing on me it says this:

```
Completely ignored arguments: [--nativeLauncherVersion, 307]
[11:32:52] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: Crophius
[11:32:54] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.4
[11:32:54] [Client thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
[11:32:59] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Starting up SoundSystem...
[11:32:59] [Thread-5/INFO]: Initializing LWJGL OpenAL
[11:32:59] [Thread-5/INFO]: (The LWJGL binding of OpenAL.  For more information, see http://www.lwjgl.org)
[11:32:59] [Thread-5/INFO]: OpenAL initialized.
[11:32:59] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Sound engine started
[11:33:01] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 1024x512 textures-atlas
[11:33:10] [Client thread/INFO]: Connecting to mc.pixlriffs.com, 26016
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffd3807daaa, pid=22760, tid=42784
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ltc_game64-114279.dll+0x6daaa]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Maximilian\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid22760.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
[0x7FFD38078350] ANOMALY: meaningless REX prefix used
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
[0x7FFD3CC34450] ANOMALY: meaningless REX prefix used
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

I'm running on Windows 10 and Minecraft 1.10.2

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that either loading OpenAL failed or there's no OpenAL installation on your system.

OpenAL is a driver interface similar to OpenGL, just for your audio hardware.

Look in `C:\Windows\System32` and see if there's a file called `OpenAL32.dll`. If it isn't, you don't have it installed.

You can [download it from the official OpenAL website](https://www.openal.org/downloads/). (Make sure to grab the Windows installer, not the SDK.)

Comment: I have a new problem now, i have enabled minidumps but it says i have not: